# Is it possible to create a custom page layout with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

What I would like to achieve is a bit like this

[image]

Where "some view" is some custom content (either a page or content view) that is fixed and never changes (like a status bar) and the page would change by normal navigation (through the NavigationPage).

I already have something similar working but "some view" gets re-created every time the user navigates because every page derives from a base page that contains "some view".

```
public sealed class RootPage : ExtendedMasterDetailPage
{
    public RootPage()
    {
        // 30%
        DrawerWidth = .3f;
        Master = new MenuPage();
        Detail = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
    }
} 

public abstract class MasterPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly Grid _root;
    private View _content;

    // Subclasses set this property to add their content
    public View Detail
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set
        {
            if (_content != null)
                _root.Children.Remove(_content);
            _content = value;
            if (_content != null)
                _root.Children.Add(_content, left: 0, top: 1);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected MasterPage()
    {
        _root = new Grid
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition {Height = new GridLength(60, GridUnitType.Absolute)},
                new RowDefinition {Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)},
            },
            RowSpacing = 0
        };

        // BuildStatusBar() creates the "static" content that is placed above the page
        _root.Children.Add(BuildStatusBar(), left: 0, top: 0);

        Content = _root;
    }
}

public sealed class HomePage : MasterPage
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        // Build content
        Detail = ...
    }
}
```

On [this blog post](http://intellectualponderings.blogspot.fr/2014/10/xamarin-forms-reusable-custom-content.html) the author does something similar to me but in XAML, and he seems fine with his content being reloaded every time; whereas I want that **only the content page** changes and the header "some view" stays there.

I believe I would need some custom renderer, and the best documentation on that seems to be [this swipe to refresh custom renderer](http://motzcod.es/post/103224921992/pull-swipe-to-refresh-for-xamarin-forms-android). However I cannot figure out how to apply it to my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can that achieve in Xamarin.Forms.

**You can change the contents of the content view inside it with animation**, but that wont be a right thing to do.
It wont be possible (or too much efforts) to go back through hardware keys.

Comment: Yeah that was a long time ago :) we ended up scraping Xamarin.Forms and going for Xamarin Android directly. We implemented it with fragments.

Comment: LOL didnt see it was a 2014 question :P